# Is it unlikely Synchronous XMLHttpRequests from web pages will be dissabled

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

AS far as I've been able to research, disallowing this will take a "long time", and there seems to be less and less consensus to finally remove it. Without going into unnecessary detail, I've used a few of these on some pages because it is the perfect solution. First, since I'm calling a PHP script on my own hosted server, there is no way it could take so long as to cause the "detrimental effects to the end user's experience" the console warnings tell me about, and second, the user requested action cannot continue until the request completes anyway.

So the only reason I would re-work these pages to for a work-around is if it is really going to go away. So is removal actually scheduled? Is it as unlikely enough to not worry about it?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely, just in the main thread. For example, there is nothing wrong with synchronous XHR in a web worker - but eventually, yes it will be removed everywhere else.

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is in the process of being removed from the web platform as it has detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. (This is a long process that takes many years.) Developers must not pass false for the async argument when current global object is a Window object. User agents are strongly encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools and may experiment with throwing an "InvalidAccessError" DOMException when it occurs.

-[The Spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method).

Comment: I've read that spec, noticed the "in the process of being removed" verbage, along with many blogs referencing it  for several years, saying its unlikely to ever be removed. Considering its 2019 and my pages still work (albeit with said warning in the CONSOLE view), I'm becoming hopeful that "removing" or "blocking" it is becoming as unlikely as the promised removal of the html <center> tag.

Comment: dude you asked a question, i answered. if you wanna argue about it go to reddit. it *will* be removed from the web. period. they already have the error it will throw in the spec. that doesn't mean they're removing it from the function, it will still be available in workers. start converting your code to use modern scripting practices before it's too late.

Comment: Geeze. I was asking WHEN, and WHETHER the function would STOP working. Yes, in the main thread!  Quoting the spec is not an answer, as I already quoted part of it in my question. I happen to like to maintain support for old browsers, which do not support worker threads. That means double work. So  as the spec says the "process may take many years", it doesn't hurt to ask when. I never know when someone actually part of the decision making process might know.

Comment: you don't need synchronous code to support old browsers. even IE3 supported callback functions all the way back in the mid 90's.

Comment: Well yes... a simple callback. But again without going into too much detail, there are times when a call to a local PHP script has to complete, during a page's window.onload() event for example, in order for important page alterations to be made, before the visitor interacts. I suppose I could put up a "spinning wheel page loading" display and let the callback do the rest of the page processing and remove the "wait wheel", But I had thought actual instantiated worker threads were needed. Its still a PITA to fix pages that work though. So a time frame would be good to know.

Comment: OT possibly, as it would in effect be arguing with the SPEC (a moot thing to do). But it seems that my particular usage could not possibly have a "detrimental effects to the end user’s experience" unless the server was down. In that case all bets are off anyway.  Is it possible for lay coders to contribute the the decision making process, and make a case for continuance?

Comment: to contribute you can make a proposal to [TC39](https://github.com/tc39) and hope it gets a sponsor. you can monitor and comment by joining the es-discuss mailing list. there is no timeline as these are community supported standards and specs.. it just depends on when they have time to get around to it. most of the people contributing are volunteers and have their own day jobs.

Comment: Appreciated. I found this discussion on GitHub too, which seems to corroborate that removal won't come any time soon. 
https://github.com/whatwg/xhr/issues/20   I'll upvote your answer ans I appreciate the discussion, and will attempt an async callback work-around. Though I'm still hoping to know well in advance of a deadline.